# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

[This one here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74808/more-nuanced-measures-of-internet-utilization-in-a-place). Is it outside the scope for asking ways to quantify sociological phenomena?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The people who voted to close the question did not leave any comments explaining why. So I can only guess what their motivations could have been.

But one reason could be that it's not really "about governments, policies and political processes". Internet access is usually provided by private companies. Governments usually only have indirect influence. They can use subsidies, taxes and regulations to encourage or discourage companies from building internet infrastructure and offering affordable plans to people, but in the end it's up to the companies in which regions they decide to put up cellphone towers and lay down cables.

Another reason could be that it is the kind of question where there are no right or wrong answers. It's kind of a brainstorming question where people can come up with all kinds of ideas how the effects of internet access on peoples lives could be quantified. And it's hard to tell which aspects of life would be relevant to you and which quantifications would actually be useful for your purpose.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I agree with the vote mainly because it isn't really about governments, policies, or political processes. I think there was a comment saying that it may be better suited for Economics.SE. And, by the name of that site, it sounds like it may be. Although I am not familiar enough with that site to be able to say whether this particular question would do well there.